# How to: Angular Tree?

Tags: angularjs

Hi all you experts out there.

My testing area: http://plnkr.co/edit/ddJT1e4a8L5NTSIVNTk7

I am trying to visualize hierarchical data in a tree-form with Angular, even though i'm using some samples to aid me in my quest (like http://jsfiddle.net/alalonde/NZum5/ and http://jsfiddle.net/brendanowen/uXbn6/8/) i fail.

[image: Global structure]

As soon as i place the recursive element `ng-include` inside the `ng-repeat` in side the template it self, the memory usage of its browser-window goes through the roof and effectively hangs the browser. But the available tree-sample i could find are doing just that.

What am i missing?

Comment: to make peoples lives a bit easier: https://github.com/dotJEM/angular-tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same variable name in the template. The current node is called **node** in the controller then **child** in the template.

This cause the template to render the same node over again.
It works fine if you use the same variable name :

```
<li ng-repeat="node in node.children" ng-include="'node.html'"></li>
```

See it in action here : http://plnkr.co/edit/mjfdSEDcMK8kGCRjS6V6?p=preview

Comment: This indeed works, feels a little strange though 'overriding' a variable this way.

Comment: It is a question of scope. The template is applied into the ng-repeat from your list. As the template explicitly referes to a variable called 'node' (which was defined in the controller) that one will be used unless it is defined in a closed scope. The spike in memory usage indicates that there was an infinite loop as that node defined in the controller always has 3 childrens which will be looped over forever.

Comment: @SvenL make sure to add ng-show="node.isOpen" to your ul element

Answer (score 0):

If anyone here wants to avoid having the extra `ng-repeat` outside of the template (where it kind of includes stuff from the template anyway), here's a fiddle showing how to do it:

http://jsbin.com/hokupe/1/edit

Also here's a blog post and a 10-15 minutes video on how it works:

http://gurustop.net/blog/2014/07/15/angularjs-using-templates-ng-include-create-infinite-tree/

Sample Code:

```
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="treeLevel.html">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input type="checkbox"
          name="itemSelection"
          ng-model="item._Selected" />
        {{item.text}}
        <div ng-include=" 'treeLevel.html'"
            onload="items = item.children">
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </script>
  <div ng-include=" 'treeLevel.html' "
       onload="items = sourceItems">
  </div>
```